# parent div don't wrap child div

Tags: html, css

I have nner and outer div.

normally the parent div wrap the child div but in my case child div have the same width than the parent.

I'm expecting that `inner-container` width is the same as input and not outer-container
Here an example to well understand

```css
.outer-container{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.innercontainer {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class ="outer-container">
  <div class=" innercontainer">
    <div>
     Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try assigning `display:inline-block` to your `innercontainer` element. Try this code.

```
.innercontainer {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Its because `div` element is block element by default and all block elements take width equal to 100% width of its parent. So, you make it `display:inline-block` and it takes width only equal to the content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to `.innercontainer`:

```
display: inline-block;
```

https://codepen.io/amitozdeol/pen/LrbvBo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block;` like that :

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.innercontainer {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class=" innercontainer">
    <div>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```